# Get SVG path coords without drawing

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I want to get coordinates of a path using `pointAt()`. Is it possible to use the path object without drawing it?

Now I am doing as follows. But this needs an element with id `'#drawing'`.

```
var draw = SVG('drawing');
var path = draw.path(pathData);
var pathLength = path.length();
var point5 = path.pointAt(5);
```

Can I use the path without the draw variable?

Comment: Probably? Have you tried?

Comment: What's the problem with drawing it?

Comment: I want to move the contents of a canvas according to the path data. For this I don't want to draw an SVG in my page.

Comment: Try `$('#drawing').css('visibility','hidden');`

Comment: I know I can hide it :) But what I require is I don't want the browser to draw it. What if the browser doesn't support SVG? I want to know whether its possible to get path details without relying on browser SVG support using svg.js?

Answer (score 0):

svg.js will always append the newly created path to the dom when created on the standard way. However if you dig a bit you will find this solution:

```
var path = (new SVG.Path).plot(pathData)
var point5 = path.pointAt(5);
console.log(point5);
```

This will create the path only internally and will not appending it to the dom.